# Modal Windows on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I have displayed simple login page on modal window in visualforce page. Login page have the forgot password link, once i click on that link we need to display the forgot password page on same modal window without creating new modal window.

Currently, i click on the forgot password link its showing new modal window on login modal window. How can we dispaly the login and forgot password page in single modal window?

Please help on this..

Thanks,
MRH

Comment: can you add your code?